# Al pasar un FormControl al hijo, este no es notificado cuando desde el padre cambia algún estado

Tags: angular, angular5, reactiveformsmodule

Tengo el componente input

```html
<div>
  <input
    [type]="type"
    [name]="name"
    [id]="name"
    [ngClass]="{
      'border-red-500': shouldApplyRedBorder(),
      'bg-gray-50': !shouldApplyRedBorder(),
      'border border-gray-300': true,
      'text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500': true
    }"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
  />
</div>
```

Hago uso de este componente desde el componente de login form

```html
<app-input
      [control]="loginForm.get('password')"
      [name]="'password'"
      [type]="'password'"
      [placeholder]="'••••••••'"
    ></app-input>
```

Ahora el problema es que cuando hay algun cambio en el estado del formControl, el padre no notifica al hijo, por lo que nunca se ejecuta ninguna de las funciones del hijo.